# Git clone http with password

Tags: git, github

I am trying to clone a private git repository via http. There is a similar question here: [Git clone using http with user and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030698/git-clone-using-http-with-user-and-password).

Is there a way to do git clone without entering a user/password at the prompt?

When I try and do:

```
prodroom15:mquimiro$ git clone https://github.com/user:password/Automator.git
Cloning into 'Automator'...
Username for 'https://github.com': 
Password for 'https://github.com':
```

How would I do this so that I don't have to type in the user/password manually?

Note that doing the normal `https://github.com/user/Automator.git` and manually entering in the user/password at the prompt works fine.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the syntax is actually `https://user:password@github.com` not `https://github.com/user:password`.

If you are using Git 1.7.9 or later, consider using the more secure [credential helper mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github).

Comment: Thanks, the case was reversed syntax.

Comment: just a quick not that the full url would then be something like this `https://user:password@github.com/user/myrepo.git`

Comment: What happens (in terms of security) if I use http instead of https?